# internal server error 500 when using axios post/get in azure web app for fullcalendar

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure, axios

Having trouble with get/post in axios when deployed to azure web app, everything works in local pc.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },

    url: '/Admin/Events/AddEvent',
    data: {...}
})
.then(res=>...)
.catch(err => alert(`8881 Something went wrong 88: ${err}`));
```

### output

For post method => 400 (Bad Request)

Request URL: https://xxx/Admin/Events/AddEvent
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 400 Bad Request
Remote Address: xxxx
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

For get method =>  500 (Internal Server Error)

I've tried the following (all works locally)

1. adding CORS

   services.AddCors(options =>
               {   ...
2. Using stringify(data)

   3. changing url to full https://xxx/Admin/Events/AddEvent
   4. different style of post e.g.
      axios.post('https://xxx/Admin/Events/AddEvent',{

Any other debugging methods will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you publish your API on your local IIS and debug it?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message which means something crashed in the server code. You can't fix anything from just that information. You need to check the logs in the web app to get the real exception details. Then you'll have some indication of the nature of the error. If your application isn't configured to log exceptions, then you need to add that feature and try your code again.

Comment: P.S. This error is very unlikely to be a CORS error, I assume that was just a random guess. If you had a CORS error, you'd see a CORS error in the browser (because CORS restrictions are actually enforced by your browser, on the basis of headers sent by the server).

Comment: @A.Nadjar OP already said " everything works in local pc". And a wrong URL would more likely to cause a 404 than a 500.

Comment: thank you so much for all your suggestions. I've found the problem, the axios statement in the javascript has a result and catch statement and for some weird reason when its deployed in azure the results message wasn't properly populated. I wrote multiple console.log statements and deployed the app more than 30 times.